# Adding prediacte disables parallel execution

Tags: sql-server, parallel-processing

I have a modified TPC-H 20 Query which has an unexpected behavior depending on the predicates. I narrowed down the query to the main problem. Except for the QIDTABLE which has a single column with ids (1, 2, 3,...) all other tables are the default TPC-H tables. Below is the basic query. This query runs in parallel and uses all the specified CPUs it should.

```
  select 
    qid, ps_suppkey
  from
    tpch.partsupp, tpch.part, tpch.qidtable 
  where
      qid < 1
      and (
            (p_name like 'burlywood%' and qid = 0)
          )
      and ps_availqty > (
        select 0.5 * sum(l_quantity)
        from tpch.lineitem
        where
           l_partkey = ps_partkey
           and l_suppkey = ps_suppkey
           and (
                 ((l_shipdate between '1994-01-01' and '1995-01-01') and qid = 0)
               )
      )
```

However, if I add some more predicates that involve the qid, the query uses only a single core and it takes forever to finish. Here is an example:

```
  select 
    qid, ps_suppkey
  from
    tpch.partsupp, tpch.part, tpch.qidtable 
  where
      qid < 2
      and (
            (p_name like 'burlywood%' and qid = 0) or
            (p_name like 'burlywood%' and qid = 1)
          )
      and ps_availqty > (
        select 0.5 * sum(l_quantity)
        from tpch.lineitem
        where
           l_partkey = ps_partkey
           and l_suppkey = ps_suppkey
           and (
             ((l_shipdate between '1994-01-01' and '1995-01-01') and qid = 0) or
             ((l_shipdate between '1994-01-01' and '1995-01-01') and qid = 1)
               )
      )
```

I figured out that this is caused by the inner select that computes the sum:

```
((l_shipdate between '1994-01-01' and '1995-01-01') and qid = 0) or
((l_shipdate between '1994-01-01' and '1995-01-01') and qid = 1)
```

Having multiple predicates here disables the parallel execution. In this case here, since the dates are the same for both predicates, I could rewrite it as:

```
((l_shipdate between '1994-01-01' and '1995-01-01') and (qid = 0 or qid = 1))
```

In this form the query is executed in parallel again but usually the dates are different and I cannot combine them.

Why is that and what exactly is the difference between those two versions?

**Edit:**
Here is a more complex query with different predicate values for a better understanding:

```
select 
  qid, ps_suppkey
from
  tpch.partsupp, tpch.part, tpch.qidtable 
where
  qid < 3
  and (
        (p_name like 'burlywood%' and qid = 0) or
        (p_name like 'bisque%' and qid = 1) or
        (p_name like 'almond%' and qid = 2)
      )
  and ps_availqty > (
    select 0.5 * sum(l_quantity)
    from tpch.lineitem
    where
       l_partkey = ps_partkey
       and l_suppkey = ps_suppkey
       and (
            ((l_shipdate between '1994-01-01' and '1995-01-01') and qid = 0) or
            ((l_shipdate between '1997-01-01' and '1998-01-01') and qid = 1) or
            ((l_shipdate between '1992-01-01' and '1993-01-01') and qid = 2)
           )
  )
```

Comment: I would recommend you start using aliases and reference all your columns with the alias so you know what table they come from. Also, you should avoid using a comma separated list of table names. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: Your second query and the first query are not really the same thing. You have a top 1 (with no order by, which is not a good practice) on the second query. But on the first query there is no top 1.

Comment: @SeanLange tpc-h tables have their columns prefixed with the table's shortcut, e.g. the p_ for Part table or ps_ Partsupp table. I forgot to remove the 'top 1'. It was just for testing, the problem still is the same. I'll remove it. Thanks for the link and info I'll look into it and try to rewrite.

Comment: I am guessing that tpc-h means something to somebody but I have no idea what that means.

Comment: The TPC Benchmark™H (TPC-H) is a decision support benchmark. It consists of a suite of business oriented ad-hoc queries and concurrent data modifications. It has predefined tables and queries which can be used to benchmark a database system.

Answer (score 0):

You could greatly simplify the where predicates in your second query. This should be the same thing.

```
where
    --qid < 2 this is redundant, it already deals with this in the next predicate
    p_name like 'burlywood%'
    and qid in (0, 1)
    and ps_availqty > 
    (
        select 0.5 * sum(l_quantity)
        from tpch.lineitem
        where
            l_partkey = ps_partkey
            and l_suppkey = ps_suppkey
            and l_shipdate between '1994-01-01' and '1995-01-01'
            and qid in (0, 1)
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll try this out. In this case its straight forward because the values are the same in both cases. This is usually not the case but it should be applicable for more complex queries. I will edit the question with an more complex example. I welcome any refactory advices :)